# Are there some ways to use wiktionary to find related terms more easily?

Tags: tools, resources, dictionary

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=500&offset=0&profile=default&search=insource%3A+ship&ns0=1

I was trying to use insource to find all terms related to ships, but obviously it didn't work, I am wondering if there are ways to achieve this that I am not aware of. I remember there were categories of words, but I can't seem to find them anymore.

Comment: Does it need to involve wiktionary? It might help to state the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than just the issue with how you tried to solve it.

Comment: Please don't put your answers in the question, either. That's not where they go. I understand that you are upset about the downvotes you're receiving, and we're already doing everything we can about the serial downvotes you were receiving, **but that does not give you the right to abuse the way the site works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps https://relatedwords.org might suit your needs. ([Here's a link for ship](https://relatedwords.org/relatedto/ship).)
I don't think the site uses wiktionary, but it does provide a long list of related words.

Another, very similar site, is https://relatedwords.io ([ship-link](https://relatedwords.io/ship))

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:en:Nautical

I was able to find an actually really good way to search for these words.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:en:All_topics

There are several categories, but now I am trying to figure out how to use this in the input search bar.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#incategory:

This link shows you how to use incategory, but it doesn't seem to work on Wiktionary as of now.

mast "en:Nautical" works, but I can't use mast incategory:"en:Nautical", mast incategory:en:Nautical, mast incategory:Nautical or any other similar option

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=500&offset=0&ns0=1&search=mast+%22en%3ANautical%22

We can also use: ship insource: "en:nautical", but the results include pages without the word ship in it somehow.

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=500&offset=0&ns0=1&search=ship+insource%3A+%22en%3Anautical%22

Comment: Maybe you can try `ship linksto:nautical` (i.e. pages with "ship" that link back to the "nautical" page). But it's weird how `incategory:` or `deepcat:` doesn't seem to work for categories starting with `en:`, other categories do seem to work. It might be a bug in their search.